# Tokenize a particular column in a particular row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called Constants with a column called called "constant_value" and from this on a particular row I want to tokenize a string by "," to use in a IN clause.

How can I do it in a oracle query?

I found that I can use the following query but it does not return the required data. What I am doing wrong here?

```
select regexp_substr(c.constant_value,'[^,]+', 1, level) 
from  connstants c where c.name='RELAX' 
connect by regexp_substr(c.constant_value, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle with sample data and your data layout?

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to flatten rows into a csv list. This any good:

```
select 
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, c.constant_value || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') the_list
from    connstants c 
where c.name='RELAX' ;
```

See also SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH